# JUnit: How avoid verbose/repeated data in @Parameters? (Refactoring)

Tags: junit, junit4

Working with `JUnit`.

For a Test class I have two instance variables:

```
private final Locale locale;
private final PersonaValidationUpdate personaUpdateInvalid;
```

Their values are defined through `@Parameters`. Of course it with the intention to use both in a `@Test` method

I use:

```
@Parameters(name="{index}: Locale: ''{0}'' - ''{1}'' ")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            { ClientUserLocale.ENGLISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.NULL},
            { ClientUserLocale.ENGLISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.EMPTY},
            { ClientUserLocale.ENGLISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.MIN},
            { ClientUserLocale.ENGLISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.MAX},

            { ClientUserLocale.PORTUGUESE.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.NULL},
            { ClientUserLocale.PORTUGUESE.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.EMPTY},
            { ClientUserLocale.PORTUGUESE.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.MIN},
            { ClientUserLocale.PORTUGUESE.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.MAX},

            { ClientUserLocale.SPANISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.NULL},
            { ClientUserLocale.SPANISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.EMPTY},
            { ClientUserLocale.SPANISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.MIN},
            { ClientUserLocale.SPANISH.getLocale(), PersonaValidationUpdate.MAX}
        });
    }
```

Even when the code shown above works, is verbose, imagine if we add a new `Locale` (i.e.: *Japan*). I must add a new block and repeat `ClientUserLocale.JAPANESE.getLocale()` **4** times.

Is there a way to reduce the code shown above?

My goal is test

```
PersonaValidationUpdate.NULL
PersonaValidationUpdate.EMPTY
PersonaValidationUpdate.MIN
PersonaValidationUpdate.MAX
```

Where for each item from above, should be tested for all the `Locale`s available through my `ClientUserLocale` enum. In this case I only have 3 defined.

Comment: What about looping through the `ClientUserLocale` values and adding a new item in the list for each of `NULL`, `EMPTY`, `MAX`, `MIN`? This way the code will never change no matter if you add or remove new enum values...

Comment: Hello, `PersonaValidationUpdate` is other enum creating invalid entities according each case or scenario. Would be possible see a code to get a better understanding?

Comment: If `PersonaValidationUpdate` is also an enum, then it may be even simpler. Take a look at my answer below, and let me know your thoughts / doubts.

Comment: Let me test it in the night. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: code may not compile, it's just written based on the OP's description and code snippets

---

```java
@Parameters(name = "{index}: Locale: ''{0}'' - ''{1}'' ")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ClientUserLocale locale : ClientUserLocale.values()) {
        for (PersonaValidationUpdate validation : PersonaValidationUpdate.values())
            data.add(new Object[]{locale.getLocale(), validation});
    }

    return data;
}
```